# Python Library for packet creation//manipulation

Tags: python, libpcap

I am currently working on libpcap-python, I found it does not help(I don't know how) in modifying packet data. Is there any library which can be used to create network packet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you have a look at scapy

- http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/